# Why is Bigg Boss written with two Gs'?

Tags: title, bigg-boss

[*Bigg Boss*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigg_Boss) is Hindi adaptation of [*Big brother*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Brother_(U.S._TV_series)). There are also [regional adaptations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigg_Boss#Versions) to the same show with language name at the end. But my question is why it is written Bigg with two gs' in the name? In the original series Big Brother, the spelling has a single G but why was it changed? Is there any reason for that change?

Comment: By repeating biGG, it may be a try of indicate that the meaning of the word **big** should be the biggest highlight. it's like saying baddest. while baddest is not a regularly used word(in UK english anyways..) but It means someone/thing is way more bad than usually saying 'eh, he's bad' but something like *he's very very bad. oh, I can't stress this enough. you really really should concentrate on how **bad** he is*. IMO

Comment: Don't know specifically about Bigg Boss but Indian TV serials have a trend of misspelling/adding alphabet to the title due to astrology/numerology. Remember Dill Mill Gayyee with extra letters. Also Koffee with Karan instead of Coffee. Ekta Kapoor had a history of adding extra k eg Kkusum

Comment: To not get confused with [the other Big Bosses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Boss)?

Comment: @JAB they were not talk shows, I think, based on my googling, bigg boss is somewhat a chat/talking show

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](https://www.m9.news/movienews/rajani-believes-in-numerology-makes-changes-in-title/) numerology prompted the change in the title, in order to promote luck.

> Silverscreen God Rajanikanth also seeks divine’s help. He proved that
> he is not exceptional in believing astrology and numerology which play
> key role in film circles. With the suggestion from well known
> numerologists, extra ‘I’ was added to the title of his new film
> ‘Kochadaiiyaan’.
>
> Numerologist Sanjay strongly defended slight change in the title
> saying that modification brought success to many stars including
> Akshay Khanna, Shahrukh Khan and others. For instance, “Dabangg’s
> extra ‘g’ has given Salman Khan a big success. **Bigg Boss, also with a
> double ‘g’, has propelled success to the movie makers.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Rajani believes in numerology, makes changes in title!](https://www.m9.news/movienews/rajani-believes-in-numerology-makes-changes-in-title/)</sup></sub>

Numerologist Sanyjay Jumaani (and his son) has made repeated claims that adding the second g was his suggestion and that it made the show lucky, with the two letters adding up to 24, which he claims is a lucky number.

> He added, "Furthermore, it's worth mentioning that he was even approached to
> participate in the show over a decade ago but respectfully declined for similar
> reasons as mine. In a fascinating twist, he also contributed to the show's
> unique spelling by suggesting the double 'G' in the title 'Bigg Boss,' symbolising
> extra 'Good Luck.'"
>
> <sub><sup>[Sanjay B Jumaani’s son Aneesh on his participation in Salman](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/articleshow/103582295.cms?utm_source=contentofinterest&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=cppst)</sup></sub>

and

> Bigg Boss 13 Vs IPL 13 Let’s analyse the two names.
>
> Bigg Boss adds to 24 with the double G that we added during its
> inception.
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/sanjaybjumaani/p/B9rJa_AJb8y/)</sup></sub>

and

> As a matter of fact, the double ‘G’ in Bigg Boss is our tiny
> contribution that’s helped it become the longest running & most sought
> after Indian TV show, garnering enormous fame & recognition
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/CaRG0D9oNcS/)</sup></sub>